# jQuery: Animate background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Modifying [this](http://jsmadeeasy.com/javascripts/Background%20Effects/background_slide_show/index.htm) script, I'm able to go through background images and cycle them through the body 'background-image' property. However, I'm wanting to know if it's possible to use jQuery animate (or another method) to perform a fade transition. I've attempted to use other scripts, such as the jQuery cycle plugin, but the issue seems to be the fixed attribute. Here's what I have working so far:

```
<style>
body{
/*Remove below line to make bgimage NOT fixed*/
background-image:url(/sites/default/files/bg-3.jpg);
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="/sites/default/files/bg-1.jpg"
bgimages[1]="/sites/default/files/bg-2.jpg"
bgimages[2]="/sites/default/files/bg-3.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++){
pathToImg[i]=new Image()
pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}

var inc=-1

function bgSlide(){
if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
inc++
else
inc=0
$('body').css({'background-image':'url('+pathToImg[inc].src+')'});
}

setInterval(function(){
    bgSlide();
},3000);

});
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed" attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't do this exactly.

You could simulate this by having a div (or image) behind your content that acts as a background, similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HDWpM/

Answer (score 0):

David Walsh explains how you can do this with MooTools [here](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-animate-background) you can have look! You can use jQuery also, MooTools is just a different library.

Here is the demo : http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/background-animation.php